# Get system time with BIOS interrupt in assembly

Tags: assembly, interrupt, bios, emu8086, systemtime

I want to get the time(hours, minutes, second) with the interrupt INT 1Ah/AH = 00h. I know that it keeps in CX the High-order part of clock count and in                    DX the Low-order part of clock count.

I searched about it, and found the following formulas convert the clock count to
the time of day:

```
                             Hour      = Clock / 65543 (1007h)
                             Remainder = Clock MOD 65543

                             Minutes   = Remainder / 1092 (444h)
                             Remainder = Remainder MOD 1092

                             Second    = Remainder / 18.21
                             Remainder = Remainder MOD 18.21
```

But I am confused about how to use them, how can I get clock from CX and DX? Should I read into a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use that interrupt, use `INT 1Ah/02` instead. If you insist, note that `Clock` is just the 32 bit value formed from `CX` and `DX`. Putting them into a variable won't help you at all. Since you need to divide it, and the `DIV` instruction expects dividend in `DX` (high) and `AX` (low) you just have to shuffle it around a little. You will run into problems at dividing by `18.21` though. Something like this could work, but note that the constant `1092` is not accurate either. You might end up with `60` for minutes if you are unlucky (if the `clock mod 65543` happens to be above `65519`, dividing by `1092` will give you `60`.)

```
mov ax, dx           ; low 16 bits
mov dx, cx           ; high 16 bits
div word [mem_65543] ; constant in memory
mov [hours], ax
mov ax, dx           ; work with remainder
xor dx, dx           ; zero top bits
div word [mem_1092]  ; constant in memory
mov [minutes], ax
mov ax, [mem_100]    ; constant in memory
mul dx               ; scale by 100
div word [mem_1821]  ; constant in memory
mov [seconds], ax
```

Comment: I tried INT 1Ah/02 and I got an error:  "INT 1Ah, AH=02h   - not supported yet. refer to the list of supported interrupts" - I am using emu8086.

Comment: Why the last division by 100 ("scale back") ? The seconds are already in the `AX` register.

Comment: @Jester Thanks. And why are there [] brakets for the constants and hours, minutes, second? Also, should  I declare them  as db?

Comment: That's just proper intel syntax. You might be using an assembler that doesn't need it. No, those need to be words, so `dw`.

Comment: I declared the data like this                                                                              hours   dw ?
    minutes dw ?
    seconds dw ?  
    mem_65543 dw 65543
    mem_1092  dw 1092  
    mem_100   dw 100
    mem_1821  dw 1821 but I get errors. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I get (6) overflow! - cannot be evaluated: mem_65543 dw 65543
(18) wrong parameters: DIV  word [mem_65543]
(18) should be a register or a memory location.
Line 6 is mem_65543 dw 65543, line 18 is div word [mem_65543] ; constant in memory.

Comment: Duh, 65543 is of course more than a word, yay! Didn't spot that.

Comment: @Jester what can I do in this case, to get the time?

Comment: Round it down to 65536 so you can skip the division, or perform a 32 bit division. Probably easiest with repeated subtraction.

Comment: I rounded and I get the hours and minutes correct, but not the second. For example, just now I got 20:51:604, earlier I got 20:49:219. How can 2 digit seconds?

Comment: Not sure. The remainder from the division by 1092 can be 1091 at most, multiplying by 100 gives 109100 and dividing by 1821 gives 59. Use your debugger to see where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that EMU8086 is emulating 8254 timer 0, which most PC systems still emulate, here are the timing values:

```
    8254 channel 0 runs at 1.19318 mhz or ~ 838.0965 nsecs / cycle
    System timer interrupts every 65536 cycles ~= 54.9255 ms
    or ~ 18.20648 ticks per second
    1 ms   = 1193.18 cycles
    1 hour ~= 65543 ticks ~= 3599.9816 secs
   24 hour ~= 1573040 (hex 1800B0) ticks ~= 86399.998 secs
```

Example C code for precise conversion of ticks to hours / minutes / seconds (truncated):

```
    i = itick<<10;             /* itick * 1024 */
    hour = 0;
    while(i >= 67116375){
        hour++;
        i -= 67116375;
    }
    i <<= 4;                   /* itick * 16384 */
    minute = 0;
    while(i >= 17897700){
        minute++;
        i -= 17897700;
    }
    second = 0;
    while(i >= 298295){
        second++;
        i -= 298295;
    }
```

With a 32 bit by 16 bit multiply routine, you can multiply by floor((2^32)/divisor) which only needs a single subtract check after.

```
uint32_t i, tick, hour, minute, second;
/* ... */
    i = tick<<10;
    hour = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)i*63)>>32);
    i -= hour*67116375;
    if(i >= 67116375){
        hour++;
        i -= 67116375;
    }
    i <<= 4;
    minute = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)i*239)>>32);
    i -= minute*17897700;
    if(i >= 17897700){
        minute++;
        i -= 17897700;
    }
    second = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)i*14398)>>32);
    i -= second*298295;
    if(i >= 298295){
        second++;
        i -= 298295;
    }
```

With a 32 by 32 bit multiply routine, the single subtract checks can be eliminated:

```
    i = tick<<10;
    hour = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)i*2147243323u)>>57);
    i -= hour*67116375;
    i <<= 4;
    minute = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)i*4026081231u)>>56);
    i -= minute*17897700;
    second = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)i*1887225577u)>>49);
    i -= second*298295;
```